# PC to PC Serial port communication through Matlab

Tags: matlab, events, fopen, scanf, serial-communication

I have two laptops are connected via a USB cable, the USB on one end is attached to a USB to serial adapter. I need to send information from one laptop (Mac) to the other laptop (PC) through Matlab.

I know how to use `fopen` to use `serial ports` in Matlab to send these "markers" to the second laptop. However, I am unsure on how to read them at the receiving end.

I currently have the following code where the serial connection is opened:

```
  % connect to serial port to send markers
    portID = '/dev/tty.USA28X145P2.2';
    global markerID
   [markerID, err] = fopen(portID, 'w');
   if ~isempty(err)
      error('An error was returned whilst connecting to the serial port     
   to send markers. The error was:\n\t"%s"', err);
   end
```

My Matlab script then calls a function that uses `fwrite` to write the information that I need to the object that was opened using `fopen`.

Now I am unsure how to "receive" these in Matlab on the other laptop. Do I need to use `fscanf`?

I am quite new to this so I'm not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in the USB standard which allows PC to PC communication. Just using a USB cable with the right plug on both sides (which according to the standard should not exist) does not allow communication. Why did you chose USB instead of a network connection? What kind of Cable did you use to connect both systems?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I was unclear. Its not a simple USB connection but uses the keyspan to convert USB to serial adapter on both ends.

Comment: I recommend to simplify your question. It is irrelevant that you are using a USB serial adapter, and the background of your application is irrelevant as well. Your question is how to establish a serial connection between two PCs using MATLAB.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, I have removed the irrelevant stuff from my question.